# XP Clients to Sync with Server 2008 Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have around 200 XP users and one DC and one ADC.

I want to sync xp machine with DC or ADC. On DC i have given NTP server source(it is a unix server)

Currently in XP registry the NTP source is times.windows.com which i want to be my DC IP

Please tell what are the steps on server side and clients.

Comment: Are your XP clients joined to the domain? If so they should already be synchronising with the PDC emulator of your domain. What's the output of `w32tm /query /configuration` on one of your XP clients?

Comment: What exactly is an ADC and how is it different than a DC?

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown Not exactly true. All other DCs sync time from the DC holding the PDC Emulator role. All member servers and client computers sync from the DC that is their logon server.

Comment: @MDMarra absolutely correct, my bad!

Comment: the command /query is unknown

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. What exactly is an ADC and how is it different than a DC?

Comment: DC stands Domain Controller and ADC Additional Domain Controller. Normally ADC is created as a backup if DC fail's

Comment: That's not correct. There's no such thing as a backup DC or ADC. They're all multi master peers.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've changed it, the default behavior is for domain-joined computers to sync time from the DC that they used as a logon server. You don't have to configure anything special for this to happen.

Your DCs will sync time from the DC holding the PDC Emulator role. If you want your DCs to sync from an external time source, you should *only* modify the DC that holds this role. The other DCs will automatically sync from it.

Comment: i just started one machine and i looked at eventvwr and it was successfully sync'g with my DC but at another machine which i rebooted was not showing any w32 msg......and one more thing in eventvwr w32 msg show that it will try for NTP server after 15 mintues but that was not true...m still w8ing but its is not sync'g and no msg also in eventvwr...   There is a firwall so how do i check there is no issue from firewall

Comment: NTP uses port 123. Make sure that is open through your firewall. Also, is it really that hard to type out words like `waiting` and `event viewer`? This is a site for professionals, not a text message.

Comment: sorry for text message...the machine which is getting syncing with DC on that i tried to telnet that port but it didn't work..